# How do I calculate if a given day of the month is between a given date and 14 days from that date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to work out an `IF` statement and getting lost.  I am sure I've been up too long now but I just can't see it.

Here is the scenario:

```
I have a given date in E1, say June 21st (my payday).
I have a day of the month in C22 say the 11th of the month (the day a bill is due).
I have a $value in D22 (the value of the bill).
```

I need an if statement that is true if the bill is due on or after the date in E1 AND before the date in E1 + 14 days (my next payday).

Here is what I tried (note its a bit mangled from experimenting):

```
=IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(E$1),MONTH(E$1),DAY($C22))>=E$1,DATE(YEAR(E$1),MONTH(E$1),DAY(E$1)+14))>DATE(YEAR(E$1),MONTH(E$1),DAY($C22)),$D22,"")
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
=IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(E$1),MONTH(E$1),DAY($C22))>=E$1,DATE(YEAR(E$1),MONTH(E$1),DAY($C22))<E$1+14)),$D22,"")
```

(which will show D22, with your example, if 11-Jun >= 21-Jun AND 11-Jun < 21-Jun + 14 days)

Now if you want to show D22 if 11-**Jul** >= 21-Jun AND 11-**Jul** < 21-Jun + 14 days, it is more complicated because you need to check if 11 is before or after 21, and increment the month if it is before. You could do it that way:

```
=IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(E$1),MONTH(E$1)+IF($C22<DAY(E$1),1,0),DAY($C22))>=E$1,DATE(YEAR(E$1),MONTH(E$1)+IF($C22<DAY(E$1),1,0),DAY($C22))<E$1+14),$D22,"")
```

Comment: Your close :{... shows true for values 1 through 5 (in c22) false for all others.  I got it:  In the inner IF's I need to compare to DAY(E$1), not E$1.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [MEDIAN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/median-HP005209174.aspx) formula to calculate if a date is between other two dates.

In your case you have to manage to feed MEDIAN with proper dates.. For example store current day -14 in C100 replace it for function to get current date.

```
IF(E$1=MEDIAN(C100:C22),"Yes","No")
```

You can find this [link](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/06/24/between-formula-excel/) useful.

Comment: Huh?  I think you read the question too fast.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used addition to get further days. That is, I think `E1 + 14` should be the  date of your next payday.
Then the formula could be as simple as

```
=IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(E1);MONTH(E1);C22)>=E1;DATE(YEAR(E1);MONTH(E1);C22)<(E1+14));D22;0)
```

(Note: It works in Excel 2010, if I understood your question correctly)

Comment: Note C22 doesn,t contain a date.  It is a day of the month.

Comment: Right, well, replacing `C22` with `DATE(YEAR(E1);MONTH(E1);C22)` would work?